# How to store Typeface in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-typeface

I am trying to store Typeface using SharedPreferences in android. It's working fine in the emulator(android 4.4.2), but it is getting crashed when I launch my application in device(4.2.2 & 4.3.2). Please help me. thanks,

To get from the SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences fontSP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFSFONT", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),fontSP.getString("fontValue", ""+SettingsABC.getTypeface(fontStyle)));
```

To save to sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences fontSP = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("PREFSFONT", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor bgEditor = fontSP.edit();
bgEditor.putString("fontValue", "boomerang.ttf");
bgEditor.commit();
```

The Error goes like this:

> Typeface cannot be made

Answer (score 0):

`fontStyle` is presumably `null` in your `SettingsABC.getTypeface(fontStyle)`, as `fontStyle` has not been initialized yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store typeface on the sharedprefrence, for easy access you can create custom textview by extneding the textview class in which you can add fontface